# Where to report if you find a site exactly like Stack Overflow

Tags: support, clone

I found a site which is working exactly like Stack Overflow.
Should I report that to Stack Exchange? If so, how?

Comment: @hims056 : yes, actually I didn't find that question. So I post a new one. I know one of user can provide me the url of real question. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean in terms of structure, or that the content is copied

Comment: this is the site https://community.webfaction.com/questions/

Comment: The main page took 20 seconds to load. This does not impress me

Comment: It was already [reported there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137122/187824). But deleted because it uses OSQA engine which was already reported.